# How could I automate copy pasting between applications?

Tags: macos, applescript

I'd like to be able to periodically sync data between two applications without manually copy pasting. How would I accomplish this?

For example, one app might be Chrome with a Google doc open. When the other app generates some text, I'd want to be able to automatically sync that to the Google doc (without using their API, as simulated keypresses or some other method). Ideally I'd like a way to point the generating app at wherever I want the data copied, if I want to use it with a lot of different receiving apps.

Comment: _"without using their API, as simulated keypresses **or some other method**"_  So you'd like this problem solved without using any known methods ?  How do you envisage this being done, and especially between lots of different receiving applications, most of which will not respond to AppleScript.  I'm going to go out on a limb and say this is not possible to do (certainly not possible to do well).

Comment: I think you need to explain exactly what the use case is more fully/clearly, including exactly what apps are involved; and why automating the clipboard process is unacceptable (if I've understood correctly). But this is certainly not something that someone can knock up a quick script for, to say the least.

Comment: @CJK I'm ignorant of what the methods are - I am not even sure if AppleScript is the right solution, I am a novice to developing macOs applications (would you need a system extension for this?). If the answer is that it is impossible to do, that is also good to know.

Comment: @benwiggy how would one automate the clipboard? that seems like it would solve my use case. The apps involved would be one that I am developing, that generates text, and any other app on the computer that I want to input that text to.

Comment: If it's an app that you are developing, then you should be able to take the output you've generated and send it to NSPasteboard. Then you can just Paste into which ever app you need it. I can't see any other method (which involves manual selection of the app) being faster than that.

Comment: @benwiggy and OP. I'm not one to advocate for scripting the GUI, except that it's generally not acceptable for an application intended for distribution to modify the clipboard for the purposes of achieving an ulterior objective. But text can be transferred into any native macOS application's text-editable field provided that application has accessibility hooks that expose its UI to the wider environment (and most do). Webpage content is a special case but there's JavaScript for this, which is probably the scripting language to use for this whole endeavour since it can cover all the bases,.

Comment: It can potentially even cater to the apps whose accessibility options are limited or non-existent, as JavaScript can call out to Core Graphics APIs that AppleScript isn't privy to.  Another related point to the earlier one about applications intended for others to use is that _pasting_ is always a user-controlled action.  There isn't, for instance, an API to paste text from the clipboard as that would be a security issue. So I think the clipboard is not the right approach here (or anywhere, really).

Comment: @Andrew I think if you were wanting to approach the problem in a way that is inscrutable (say, if your aspirations include the Mac App Store), then your options are indeed limited, and even my previous suggestion of UI scripting would not be kosher. A service extension would be one way to do this, and apps such as PopClip utilise APIs that do what I described above but in the correct way using NSText and NSView methods. If you're a Swift programmer, that is a way better option than AppleScript or JavaScript.  But your goal isn't a trivial twenty-minute jobbie.